# Android resource linking failed error: attribute 'android:name' in <instrumentation> tag must be a valid Java class name

Tags: android, testing, android-espresso

Well, I wrote a testing code for checking to open new activity while a button click. My code is looks like

```
@Test
public void checkNewActivity() {

    onView(withId(R.id.button_open_new_activity)).perform(click());
    onView(withText("SecondActivity")).check(matches(isDisplayed()));

}
```

I also declared in both activity in the manifest.

```
<activity
        android:name=".SecondActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_second"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">

    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

But faced error in build the test file. Error

> Android resource linking failed
>   /Users/shihab/StudioProjects/AndroidTesting/app/build/intermediates/merged_manifests/debugAndroidTest/AndroidManifest.xml:9: error: attribute 'android:name' in  tag must be a valid Java class name.

Answer (score 0):

Are you added espresso libraries in gradle file?

if no follow these steps:

1- in defaultConfig add AndroidJUnitRunner:

```
defaultConfig {
        ...
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        ...
    }
```

2- in dependencies add espresso libraries:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    //espresso
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:rules:1.1.0'
    ....
}
```